# Measurability of "(multivariate) inverse transformation sampling"

Tags: probability, general-topology, continuity

Given a measure $m \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$, one can sample from $m$ using realizations of a random variable $U$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^d$. The procedure is called (multivariate if $d \ge 2$) inverse transformation sampling, and defines a map
$$
F : \mathcal P(\mathbb R^d) \times [0,1]^d \to \mathbb R^d
$$
such that, for all $m \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$, $F(m,U)$ has law $m$ whenever $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^d$.

Is the map $F$ measurable with respect to some "usual" product sigma-algebra, for example where the first coordinate is endowed with the Borel sigma-algebra associated to the weak topology?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say that the second coordinate in the domain of $F$ is $[0,1]^d$, but then pass it a random variable $U$. Random variables are functions, not points, so there is a type error here.

Comment: There is no problem and this is standard slight abuse of notation, but let me clarify. To be more rigorous, there is a probabilistic space $\Omega$ on which $U : \Omega \to [0,1]^d$ has uniform distribution. Then, for each $m \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$ the random variable $\Omega \to R^d, \omega \mapsto F(m, U(\omega))$ has law $m$. Since $U$ is uniformly distributed, it indeed takes values in $[0,1]^d$ so $F(m,U(\omega))$ is well defined for each $\omega$.

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with how inverse transform sampling works in the multivariate case. Do you know exactly how $F$ is constructed?

Comment: @forgottenarrow, the multivariate case follows from the one dimensional case, using formula like $\mathbb P(X \le x, Y \le y) = \mathbb P(Y \le y  | X \le x) \mathbb P(X \le x)$: sample from $X$ using $U_1$, then with the realization $\hat X$ sample from $Y | X \le \hat X$ using $U_2$ to obtain $\hat Y$, and $(\hat X, \hat Y)$ has the required multidimensional law. This of course generalizes to the $d$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

This map is, to begin with, not continuous, for the simple reason that we need not even have continuity in the second coordinate for the first coordinate fixed. Let $m$ be the fair coin-flipping distribution on $\{0,1\}$. Then $F(m,x)=1$ for $x>1/2$ and $F(m,1/2)=0$. So $F$
is not continuous.

Comment: Indeed, I totally agree! I am however at the end interested in *measurability* of the map F, not really continuity, but I wanted to ask a simpler question... I'll edit my question, thanks again!